# Can I use "enter" to mean "join a club"?

Tags: verbs

I think we usually say "I am going to join the basketball club."

Is it all right to say "I am going to enter the basketball club."?

I know that [**enter**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/enter) can mean "to start to take part in a particular activity or to work in a particular job," but I'm not sure that I'm using it correctly here.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/join#filters-1 seems like it's fairly clear.

Comment: You could clearly easily search that up.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Just because it's synonymous doesn't mean it's idiomatic... I would never choose to make this substitution as a native AmE English speaker.

Comment: @Catija: I waffled on whether to post an answer or comment and VtC, but it seems idiomatic enough and it's in the thesaurus....

Comment: "Enter" here sounds like you're walking into a building.

Comment: @NathanTuggy It *is* idiomatic in some cases "I'm going to enter the Marine Corps"... I would never use it for something like a basketball club.

Comment: I think this question deserves to stay open. However, questions like this are less likely to get close votes and more likely to get upvotes if the O.P. at least explains a little bit about what they already know and found out through research. ELL should be a good resource for learning "beyond" the dictionary and thesaurus, but it's hard to go there when neither the thesaurus nor the dictionary are even mentioned. More about that can be found at [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: @J.R.: Yeah, it would be fairly easy for this to be re-opened, I think, and I'd like to see that happen.

Comment: As a native AmE speaker, I would say that you can join a basketball club, but not enter one. However, if it were a basketball **tournament**, I would say that either "joining" or "entering" the tournament was fine. Once I start thinking like that, I can see how a learner could get confused and want clarification. I don't think it's a bad question.

Answer (score 5):

You can *enter* a contest, a tournament or a building.
You can *join* a contest, a league or a social group.*

In the U.S., at least in my experience, a *basketball* club is a social grouping or league.  Therefore you *join the basketball club.*

A *tennis club* on the other hand, could refer to the social group OR to a physical building it occupies.  If you *join* the tennis club, you are signing up to play tennis with other people.  If you enter the tennis club, you are walking in the front door.  Parallels exist for *yacht clubs, rowing clubs,* and *golf clubs.***    It is impossible to not note that the pastimes for which "club" is used to refer to the building are all hobbies traditionally associated with wealth.

* If you *join* a contest, there is an implication of less competitive desire than if you *enter* a contest.  You might *join* a charity race - mostly for fun, but you would *enter* the Olympics, striving to bring home gold.  You could, however, *join* the Olympic team.

** Golf clubs, of course, can also be swung.  Context matters!